# VBA Code for Fill Down Column B

Tags: vba, excel, autofill

I recently used this code that I found to help me with this issue on another spreadsheet:

```
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'Unapplied Report'!R[-1]:R[15],2,FALSE)"

Range("A2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
Selection.FillDown
```

In my initial use this code determined the dimensions of the table by selecting A1, finding the bottom of "A" that was in use, selecting the adjacent cell in column "B" and filling the cells ending with B2 adjacent to A2 where the code had started. When reusing this code to perform the same task it is filling from "B1" which is a problem because it then fills down with my header all the way to the bottom of the sheet instead of the formula.

The code I used before worked without any issue. I have pasted it below in case someone else might notice what I did differently or wrong. Thanks for any help!

```
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(RC[-1],Conveyance,0)),""Conveyance"",IF(ISNUMBER  (MATCH(RC[-1],NonConveyance,0)),""Non-Conveyance"",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(RC[-1],VA,0)),""VA Claim"",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(RC[-1],USDA,0)),""USDA Claim"",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(RC[-1],PMI,0)),""PMI Claim"",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(RC[-1],SFLS,0)),""SFLS Claim"",""Not Found""))))))"

Range("A2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
Selection.FillDown
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to make some fixes to your code first.  This should help in the long run, particularly when trying to find issues.  In the future, try to avoid selection/activate or active references.

```
Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(RC[-1],Conveyance,0)),""Conveyance"",IF(ISNUMBER  (MATCH(RC[-1],NonConveyance,0)),""Non-Conveyance"",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(RC[-1],VA,0)),""VA Claim"",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(RC[-1],USDA,0)),""USDA Claim"",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(RC[-1],PMI,0)),""PMI Claim"",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(RC[-1],SFLS,0)),""SFLS Claim"",""Not Found""))))))"

Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1).Select 'Looks like a jumble here trying to offset
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).FillDown
```

Notice my comment in your code.  Looks like some "select" miscommunication.  Let's try to fix you up with some more defined code:

```
Dim LR as Long 'LR = Last row
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Finds last row in column A

Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = _ 'Your previous formula
"=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(RC[-1],Conveyance,0)),""Conveyance"",IF(ISNUMBER  (MATCH(RC[-1],NonConveyance,0)),""Non-Conveyance"",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(RC[-1],VA,0)),""VA Claim"",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(RC[-1],USDA,0)),""USDA Claim"",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(RC[-1],PMI,0)),""PMI Claim"",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(RC[-1],SFLS,0)),""SFLS Claim"",""Not Found""))))))"
Range("B2:B"&LR).Filldown
```

This should help more clearly define what is happening.